# single value of node_id in system.runtime.queries

Tags: presto

what does node_id signifies in system.runtime.queries query ? Does it mean the node_id on which query got executed ?

We have made some changes in presto main and since then I am getting same value b0c66b07-adfd-4739-a9ab-0cea9d9ec60e for node_id for all the queries returned by

```
select * from system.runtime.queries
```

I have already tried asking the question in presto user groups(google groups) but didn't got any response

Comment: Presto executes queries via a distributed system of worker nodes controlled by a coordinator node.  I suspect that the guid you're getting back is either a coordinator node, or one of the worker nodes. 

You can find out more about how PrestoDB works here: https://aws.amazon.com/big-data/what-is-presto/

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the implementation of the `system.runtime.queries` table, specifically at [the line where `node_id` column is being populated](https://github.com/prestosql/presto/blob/5c0d5100c767511ca2d9fe4d31968346abe55b4f/presto-main/src/main/java/com/facebook/presto/connector/system/QuerySystemTable.java#L117), this column shows the node where your "meta-query" (`select * from system.runtime.queries`) is being executed. However, this query [must run on the coordinator](https://github.com/prestosql/presto/blob/5c0d5100c767511ca2d9fe4d31968346abe55b4f/presto-main/src/main/java/com/facebook/presto/connector/system/QuerySystemTable.java#L89), so this will always be the ID of the coordinator node.

Note: this has nothing to do where "actual" queries are being executed (the one which access some real data, not Presto metadata). They will typically run on multiple nodes at once.

Comment: thanks, I was afraid if all the queries were running on single node of a multi-node EMR cluster